# Excel Power Query - How to Scroll Faster when Reordering Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

Self explanatory.

When you click & drag to reorder columns, if you have to scroll left or right it is a very slow process.

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Either to speed up the scrolling or some way to say "please move column [X] before/after column [Y]" without having to click & drag at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Scroll faster using left/right keys.**

Once you have selected the column you want moving and started dragging, you can use the left/right keys to navigate the columns as fast as you need to, then just release at your target destination as usual.